# How to simply all "data" definitions having the same kind and name of a field?

Tags: haskell

I have many "data" which represent sql table in a database.

```
    data User = User { userId :: Int, userName :: String }
    data Article = Article { articleId :: Int, articleTitle :: String, articleBody :: String }
-- .......
```

All of them has the field "id" as a primary key. I wonder, is there any way to get rid of necessity to define it each time for each "data", can I anyhow simplify that? If do this:

```
class DataTable a where 
  myId :: Int
```

it won't change anything, will? I'll still have to define "id" for each data and then implement it for DataTable, in fact it'll make more complex.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's best to separate things.

```
data Identified a = Identified
  { ident :: !Int
  , payload :: a }
```

Now you can deal with identified things in an entirely uniform way.

Comment: how can I apply it to my case?

Answer (score 2):

In GHC 8.0 with [DuplicateRecordFields](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/DuplicateRecordFields) you can use the same record field name for many data types. This is part of the larger feature of [OverloadedRecordFields](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/Redesign).

Part 3, [MagicClasses](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/MagicClasses), introduces derivable type classes for `HasField` and `UpdateField`. This is similar in idea to your `DataTable`.

If you want a field in your data type then you must declare it in the data type definition. I am not aware of any extensions, other than [Template Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_Haskell), which change this.

Comment: I think `DuplicateRecordFields` solves a different problem than the user is asking about. (Although I am glad to learn about it!)